# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables (macOS: Big Sur)

Tags: c, bash, gcc

I'm currently making my first operating system and It seems I'm having errors pop up while I'm installing gcc. I'm using macOS Big Sur, and I haven't found any helpful information that could help with my situation.

The problem:

```
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/tmp/src/binutils-build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

This is my config.log generated:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../binutils-2.24/configure --target=i386-elf --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --prefix=/usr/local/i386elfgcc

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Camerons-MacBook-Air.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 20.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 269 tasks, 1687 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 4.42, Mach factor: 1.19
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2317: checking build system type
configure:2331: result: i386-apple-darwin20.6.0
configure:2378: checking host system type
configure:2391: result: i386-apple-darwin20.6.0
configure:2411: checking target system type
configure:2424: result: i386-pc-elf
configure:2478: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2546: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2557: checking whether ln works
configure:2579: result: yes
configure:2583: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2587: result: yes
configure:2594: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2658: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:2667: checking for gawk
configure:2697: result: no
configure:2667: checking for mawk
configure:2697: result: no
configure:2667: checking for nawk
configure:2697: result: no
configure:2667: checking for awk
configure:2683: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2694: result: awk
configure:3962: checking for gcc
configure:3989: result: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
configure:4218: checking for C compiler version
configure:4227: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 --version >&5
../binutils-2.24/configure: line 4229: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9: No such file or directory
configure:4238: $? = 127
configure:4227: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 -v >&5
../binutils-2.24/configure: line 4229: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9: No such file or directory
configure:4238: $? = 127
configure:4227: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 -V >&5
../binutils-2.24/configure: line 4229: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9: No such file or directory
configure:4238: $? = 127
configure:4227: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 -qversion >&5
../binutils-2.24/configure: line 4229: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9: No such file or directory
configure:4238: $? = 127
configure:4258: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4280: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9    conftest.c  >&5
../binutils-2.24/configure: line 4282: /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9: No such file or directory
configure:4284: $? = 127
configure:4321: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4327: error: in `/tmp/src/binutils-build':
configure:4331: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-apple-darwin20.6.0
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=i386-elf
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
ac_cv_host=i386-apple-darwin20.6.0
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
ac_cv_target=i386-pc-elf
acx_cv_prog_LN=ln

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='awk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
EXTRA_CONFIGARGS_LIBJAVA='--disable-static'
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GCJ_FOR_BUILD='$(GCJ)'
GCJ_FOR_TARGET=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../binutils-2.24/configure --target=i386-elf --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --prefix=/usr/local/i386elfgcc'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-apple-darwin20.6.0'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='i386'
build_libsubdir='build-i386-apple-darwin20.6.0'
build_noncanonical='i386-apple-darwin20.6.0'
build_os='darwin20.6.0'
build_subdir='build-i386-apple-darwin20.6.0'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='apple'
clooginc=''
clooglibs=''
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl cloog libelf libiconv texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='i386-apple-darwin20.6.0'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='i386'
host_noncanonical='i386-apple-darwin20.6.0'
host_os='darwin20.6.0'
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='/usr/local/i386elfgcc'
program_transform_name='s&^&i386-elf-&'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='i386-pc-elf'
target_alias='i386-elf'
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libmudflap target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-boehm-gc target-libffi target-zlib target-libjava target-libobjc target-libada target-libgo target-rda'
target_cpu='i386'
target_noncanonical='i386-elf'
target_os='elf'
target_subdir='i386-elf'
target_vendor='pc'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='config/mh-darwin'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

If someone could help me figure out an answer for this that would be nice...

Comment: You could copy the "failed source" to a file that you try to build with `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9`, to see what really happens,

Comment: By the way, if you're building your own cross-compiler, why did you select such an old version of GCC like 4.9? That's ancient these days.

Comment: Is gcc installed as `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9` on your machine? If not, install it.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was uninstalling Xcode Command line tools and re-installing it. I guess what happened was that I had an older Xcode Command line tool that  was a leftover from a Mac OS upgrade.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```